# $PATH is not registering the updated cabal version

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

After I update cabal

```
cabal --version
```

gives me the same old version.

This is what is on my path running OS x Maverics

```
/Users/peter/.cabal/bin://anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/Library/Haskell/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Now my question is what needs to be done for my to use the updated version of cabal?

**Update1.**

I updated cabal using:

```
cabal install cabal cabal-install
```

Also `which cabal` returns `/usr/bin/cabal`

Comment: How did you update `cabal` ?

Comment: what does `which cabal` tells you?

Comment: Do you have a ``cabal`` binary in your directory ``/Users/peter/.cabal/bin``? Does ``~/.cabal/bin/cabal --version`` worked for you? How is your ~/.cabal/config file look like?

Comment: bash: /Users/peter/.cabal/bin/cabal: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, the default install location seems to be in `~/Library/Haskell/` (`bin/` for binaries, `lib/` for libs and so on).

In your `$PATH` this comes after `/usr/bin` so that's why you get the executable from there.

Try moving `~/Library/Haskell/bin` in front of `$PATH` or removing the `x` flag on `/usr/bin/cabal` :)

Comment: My path is now looking like this: ~/Library/Haskell://anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:~/Library/Haskell/bin:/opt/X11/bin but I'm still having all the same problems as before.

Comment: Should be `~/Library/Haskell/bin` for the binary to run.